# How do you add a CLOB column with a separate tablespace to an existing Oracle table?

Tags: oracle, clob

I'm trying to add a CLOB column with a separate tablespace to an existing Oracle table.  The existing table, "articles":

```
create table articles (
    id           number,
    title        varchar2(100),
    published    timestamp;
) tablespace TS_DATA;
```

has no CLOB columns.  I've created a separate tablespace to hold the CLOB data:

```
create tablespace TS_LOB
    datafile size 1024M autoextend on next 1024M maxsize 32767M;
```

When I try the following to add the CLOB column to "articles" as SYS using:

```
alter table articles add (content clob)
    lob (content) store as basicfile art_content_seg (tablespace TS_LOB);
```

I get:

```
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TS_LOB'
```

There is plenty of space on disk to accommodate the tablespace.

**SOLUTION**
I found the problem.  I needed to issue:

```
alter user <TABLE OWNER> quota unlimited on TS_LOB;
```

Previously I had issued:

```
grant unlimited tablespace to <TABLE OWNER>;
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: "no privileges" has nothing to do with the free space. Your (Oracle) user simply is not _allowed_ to use that tablespace

Comment: SYS isn't allowed to use a tablespace?

Comment: Unless you gave `SYS` the privileges to use that tablespace, then the user does not have them. I don't think there is a "use any tablespace" privilege in Oracle that `SYS` has by default. But: ***never***, ever create regular tables as `SYS` (or `SYSTEM`). **Never** store user data in the `SYSTEM` table space.

Comment: SYS wasn't the owner of the tables.  But you were correct that the tablespace quota had to be specifically set for the owner of the table.  Thanks.